# Which Glew version should I download?

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am following this OpenGL tutorial at Open.gl, it begins to speak about installing Glew.
I have found another post on Stack overflow that explains how to install it.
But which one shall I download? (Source: ZIP/TGZ | Binaries: Windows 32-bit and 64-bit)

My operating system is Windows 8.1 64bit

Glew site - http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Since you're following a tutorial, download a binary (or both). Don't waste time getting it to compile properly yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest grabbing the binaries. Grab the bitness you need to suit your compile.